# \cb not working for RTF

Tags: richtextbox, rtf

I want to highlight some texts in my RichTextBox using RTF. I have alreast used \cb and \cbpat. Both are not working. Can anyone suggest something else for highlighting text in RTF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
{\highlightN text}
```

where N is the number of the color from the color table.